# Baixa performance na RecyclerView com ConstraintLayout, dentro de um ViewPager em Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Tenho uma **RecyclerView** com cerca de 20 items. Demora bastante tempo a renderizar e bloqueia o UI.

Estou a usar o **ConstraintLayout** para posicionar items em cada linha. 
Não são nada complexos como se pode ver no preview.

Também tenho um **ViewPager** para navegação principal (ver a bottom bar). Em cada Fragment há também um ViewPager. Neste ViewPager é onde se encontra a RecyclerView (dentro de uma NestedScrollView).

Adicionalmente tenho um listener para o scroll da NestedScrollView para fazer um efeito parallax no header.

**Chamo a atenção que se remover alguns items e deixar a RecyclerView com apenas 3 items, fica muito mais rápido. Por isso, parece ser um problema com as linhas da RecyclerView.**

**Também fiz um teste e substitui o ConstraintLayout de cada linha por um FrameLayout com altura fixa - A performance não melhorou**

Estou também a usar o **Iconics** (para font icon) e **Calligraphy** (para tipografia customizada) - Poderá estar isto a afectar a performance?

---

### **Preview:**

Atenção ao círculo de touch quando tento fazer scroll imediatamente depois de mudar para a primeira página - o UI fica bloqueado. Também é visível que ao mudar para a segunda página, a animação de slide ocorre, mas quando se tenta mudar para a primeira página, a animação bloqueia, aparecendo de imediato a lista

[image: UI a bloquear quando se entra na primeira página]

**Item de cada linha** (history_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="12 JUN"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"/>

        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/date"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/kms"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="{evz_workout_running}"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="left" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBlack"
            android:text="325,4"
            android:translationY="-12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kms_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/kms"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/kms"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="KMS"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"/>




        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/kms"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:text="{evz_config_duration}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_time"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="00:00:07"/>



        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:paddingTop="2sp"
            android:paddingBottom="2sp"
            android:text="{evz_rate}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="00'00''"/>


        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:text="{evz_star}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_points"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="3500"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undo_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="Anular"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment que tem a RecyclerView (pager_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sub_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="210dp">

                <pt.sportzone.everyzone.ui.DynamicViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/sub_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ...


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

A classe do Fragment que tem o ViewPager (PagerFragment.java):

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment implements IPagerFragment, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Get elements from Layout
        mPager = (DynamicViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_pager);

        if (mButton1 != null && mButton2 != null && mButton3 != null) {
```

...

```
            if (mHeader != null) {
                // Listen to when tree is ready so we can setup parallax
                mHeader.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mHeader.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        setupParallax();
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        if (mPager != null) mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        activate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (!isVisibleToUser) activated = false;
        active = isVisibleToUser;
    }

    protected void activate() {
        if (active && getView() != null && getActivity() != null && !activated) {
            activated = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mPager == null) return;

        //Log.d(EZ.TAG, "Page Selected: " + position);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
        targetPosition = position;
        IPagerFragment fragmentAppear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(targetPosition);
        IPagerFragment fragmentDisappear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        fragmentDisappear.willDisappear(targetPosition);
        fragmentAppear.willAppear(currentPosition);

        mButton1.setSelected(false);
        mButton2.setSelected(false);
        mButton3.setSelected(false);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mButton1.setSelected(true);
                break;
            case 1:
                mButton2.setSelected(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                mButton3.setSelected(true);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mPager == null) return;

        //Log.d(EZ.TAG, position + " - " + positionOffset + " - " + positionOffsetPixels);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
        //currentPosition = position;
        if (position == targetPosition && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
            IPagerFragment fragmentAppear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(targetPosition);
            IPagerFragment fragmentDisappear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
            currentPosition = targetPosition;
            fragmentDisappear.didDisappear();
            fragmentAppear.didAppear();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void setupParallax() {

        // Listen for scroll events
        if (scrollChangedListener == null) {

            // Get initial data
            initialWidth = mBackground.getWidth();
            initialHeight = mBackground.getHeight();
            initialRatio = initialHeight / initialWidth;
            curveInitialHeight = mCurve.getHeight();

            if (mScroll != null && collapseHeader) {
                mScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                        doParallax(v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY);
                    }
                });
            }

            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mBackground);
            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mBackgroundSpacer);
            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mCurve);

            mCurve.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            // Run first parallax iteration
            doParallax(mScroll, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        }
    }

    public void doParallax(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

        // No height, something's wrong, just go away
        if (initialHeight == 0) return;

        // Get the percentage of scroll till hitting the max scroll target (initial Height)
        float percent = (float)scrollY / curveInitialHeight;

        float percentLeft = 1 - percent;

        if (percent < 0) percent = 0;
        if (percent > 1) percent = 1;

        float percentFast = Math.min(percent * 1.4f, 1);
        float percentLeftFast = 1 - percentFast;

        // Adjust the profile background image
        int headerHeight = Math.max((int)initialHeight - (int)(percent * curveInitialHeight), (int)initialHeight - (int)curveInitialHeight); // 24 -> status bar, 53 -> action bar
        UI.setConstraintHeight(mBackground, headerHeight);
        int curveHeight = Math.max((int)(percentLeft * curveInitialHeight), 0);
        UI.setConstraintHeight(mCurve, curveHeight);


        if (mButton1 != null) {
            mButton1.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
            mButton2.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
            mButton3.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
        }

        // Adjust Elements alpha
        //mBackground.getDrawable().setAlpha((int)(percentLeftFast * 255));
        //mGradient.setAlpha(percentLeft);

    }
```

And the Adapter (HistoryAdapter.java):

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT = 3000; // 3sec

private Fragment fragment;

List<Music> items;
List<Music> itemsPendingRemoval;
boolean undoOn;

private Handler handler = new Handler(); // hanlder for running delayed runnables
HashMap<Music, Runnable> pendingRunnables = new HashMap<>(); // map of items to pending runnables, so we can cancel a removal if need be

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    Music track;

    public TextView mDate;
    public IconicsTextView mIcon;
    public TextView mKms;
    public IconicsTextView mIconTime;
    public TextView mTime;
    public IconicsTextView mIconSpeed;
    public TextView mSpeed;
    public IconicsTextView mIconPoints;
    public TextView mPoints;
    public ConstraintLayout mContainer;
    public Button mUndo;

    OnHistoryItemClickedListener mListener;

    public ViewHolder(Fragment fragment, View holder) {
        super(holder);

        // Force interface implementation
        if (fragment instanceof OnHistoryItemClickedListener) {
            mListener = (OnHistoryItemClickedListener) fragment;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(fragment.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHistoryItemClickedListener");
        }
        mContainer = (ConstraintLayout) holder.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mDate = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.date);
        mIcon = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        mKms = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.kms);
        mIconTime = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_time);
        mTime = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mIconSpeed = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_speed);
        mSpeed = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.speed);
        mIconPoints = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_points);
        mPoints = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.points);

        mUndo = (Button) holder.findViewById(R.id.undo_button);

        mContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mContainer) {
            mListener.onHistoryItemClicked(this.getLayoutPosition(), track);
        }
    }

}

public interface OnHistoryItemClickedListener {
    void onHistoryItemClicked(int position, Music music);
    void onHistoryItemRemoved(int position, Music music);
}

public HistoryAdapter(Fragment fragment, List<Music> items) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.items = items;
    this.itemsPendingRemoval = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) fragment.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View track = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);
    return new HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder(fragment, track);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Music item = items.get(position);

    if (itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item)) {
        // we need to show the "undo" state of the row
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        //holder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mUndo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user wants to undo the removal, let's cancel the pending task
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = pendingRunnables.get(item);
                pendingRunnables.remove(item);
                if (pendingRemovalRunnable != null) handler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                itemsPendingRemoval.remove(item);
                // this will rebind the row in "normal" state
                notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(item));
            }
        });
    } else {
        // we need to show the "normal" state
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        //holder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //holder.titleTextView.setText(item);
        holder.mUndo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mUndo.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

    holder.track = item;

    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        holder.mContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.getContext(), R.drawable.row_with_arrow_no_border));
    } else {
        holder.mContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.getContext(), R.drawable.row_with_arrow));
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Este é o [pt.so], por favor, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, já está traduzido.